# How to install "util" (not utils) module

Tags: python, module, conda, channel

I am trying to run [the example found in the README of the PyLSCI package](https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci/blob/main/README.md#usage). It references a module `util`, so I am trying to install that through Conda, but it is not working. I have tried typing `conda install util` into the Anaconda Prompt, but I get an error that says:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels

How can I install this module?

---

#### Additional Details

- Windows OS
- Anaconda Python distribution

Comment: Are you sure that this package is available on Windows?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that. If it is not available on Windows does that mean that I can't use it at all?

Comment: I was looking for this package in PyPi and I didn't find are you sure that is the name?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to write a code similar to the one on this page: https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such "util" package. Seems like a classic grad-ware pattern: an old example is shown in the `README.md` referencing a local `util.py` file, that is kept in the release even though it is no longer relevant. Please [file an issue on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci/issues) to ask the author to update the documentation.

Comment: I filed an issue on GitHub. I don't understand why someone would create a package that uses a module that doesn't even exist

Comment: @Briget the example probably worked when they created the README and `util` was likely a *local* module relative to their development system. The developer has since changed package API, but hasn't documented it yet. Note that the date on latest release is from 5 months ago, but the README hasn't been updated in 16 months.

Comment: @Biget they have the file name `my_utils` in this address. They probably refer to that one. https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci/tree/main/binder

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned `util.py` package is only used for the `demo.ipynb`, and it is exemplarly for any custom logic that is required to convert your speckle data to NumPy arrays, which is out of scope of PyLSCI.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci/issues/7) for details, where I clearified this with [Briget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18901548/briget)

The PyLSCI package itself doesn't rely on the mentioned `util.py` to work properly, as long as you provide the speckle data as NumPy arrays.

To make that more evident, I renamed the module to `my_utils.py`, and moved it with the `demo.ipynb` notebook to the `binder` directory of the repo, also see the latest [release notes](https://github.com/pkeilbach/pylsci/releases/tag/v1.0.3) for further changes.